# Javascript widget: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<app1> has no method 'add'

Tags: javascript

Below is some example code that explains the error:

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Widget Test</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript';           
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'http://localhost/job/widget.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    })();
  </script>
  <div id="list" data-cnumber="21"></div>
</body>
</html>


widget.js:

(function() {
  var a = new app();
  var a1 = new app1();

  function app() {
    this.a;
    this.b;
  }
  app.prototype.add = function () {

  };

  function app1() {
    this.a;
    this.b;
    this.c;
    this.add();
  }
  app1.prototype.add = function () {

  };
})();
```

1. This is the error - "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'add' "
2. On doing console.log of both the objects, I can see their properties, but for some reason not their methods.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the prototype members after you have already called the constructor so they are not available during the constructor call, they have to be created before calling the constructor.

```
(function() {
  app.prototype.add = function () {

  };
  app1.prototype.add = function () {

  };

  var a = new app();
  var a1 = new app1();

  function app() {
    this.a;
    this.b;
  }


  function app1() {
    this.a;
    this.b;
    this.c;
    this.add();
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of 'app1' is called before the 'add' function is added to prototype. Try to put the call to constructor after adding the 'add' function to prototype.